# Gulp-Sass undefined variable -- Underline converting to dash

Tags: compiler-errors, sass, gulp, undefined, gulp-sass

This works in one folder, and when I cloned the repo into another folder I'm getting this error:

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    app\scss\base\_fonts.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$URL-PREFIX".
        on line 5 of app/scss/base/_fonts.scss
>>     src: url("#{$URL_PREFIX}media/fonts/Volkhov-Regular-webfont.eot");
   -------------^
```

Any Idea why it would be saying there is an error with:

```
"$URL-PREFIX"
```

instead of:

```
"$URL_PREFIX"
```

which is what is actually in the code?

Comment: did u tried after npm install ?

Comment: Yep and all of the other gulp tasks are running well.

Comment: With SASS variables, hyphens and underscores are interchangeable... odd, but yea... Per the docs: "For historical reasons, variable names (and all other Sass identifiers) can use hyphens and underscores interchangeably. For example, if you define a variable called $main-width, you can access it as $main_width, and vice versa."

Comment: ah. Thanks for the insight. It should be working. Even when I import the file with the variable immediately before this it is not recognized so I guess I'll have to do more troubleshooting.....

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like this helps with your situation in particular, but incase others came upon this post as we did, I wanted to share a possible answer.

We were dealing with the same error. It turned out that the issue occurred when the partial file was not prefixed with an underscore.

My only guess would be since it didn't have the prefix and a standalone css was being generated, the error was being thrown because the variable would not be available.

Hope this help someone.

Comment: Prefixing with an underscore fixed it for me. I think you're right about the variable scope. Thank you!